# Java 2D Array: Multiplication Table

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm not sure why my code will not work. Help please! :D

```
public static int[][] timesTable(int r, int c)
{
    int [][] yes = new int[r][c];
    for (int row = 1; row <= yes.length ; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 1; column <= yes[row].length; column++)
        {
            yes[row][column] = (row)*(column);
        }

    }
    return yes;
```

Comment: array index starts with 0, so bot of your for loops should have set the int value to 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The index of Array should start `0` rather `1`.

Change to the following code and have a try.

```
public static int[][] timesTable(int r, int c)
{
    int [][] yes = new int[r][c];
    for (int row = 0; row < yes.length ; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < yes[row].length; column++)
        {
             yes[row][column] = (row+1)*(column+1);         }

    }
    return yes;
}
```

Test code and output in console is as follows:

```
public class Test1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] data = new int[5][5];

    data = timesTable(5,5);


    for (int row = 0; row < data.length ; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < data[row].length; column++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%2d ",data[row][column]);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
}

public static int[][] timesTable(int r, int c)
{
    int [][] yes = new int[r][c];
    for (int row = 0; row < yes.length ; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < yes[row].length; column++)
        {
            yes[row][column] = (row+1)*(column+1);
        }

    }
    return yes;
}

}
```

Output in Console:

```
 1  2  3  4  5 
 2  4  6  8 10 
 3  6  9 12 15 
 4  8 12 16 20 
 5 10 15 20 25
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting ArrayIndexOutOfBounds its because you are starting from index 1, when it should be 0.

This should do the job:

```
public static int[][] timesTable(int r, int c)
{
    int [][] yes = new int[r][c];
    for (int row = 1; row <= yes.length ; row++)
    {
      for (int column = 1; column <= yes[row].length; column++)
      {
        yes[row-1][column-1] = (row)*(column);
      }

    }
    return yes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int a[][]={{2,3},{3,4}};
int b[][]={{2,3},{3,4}};
int c[][]=new int[2][2];
 for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
 for(int j=0;j<2;j++){
   c[i][j]=a[i][j]*b[i][j];
   System.out.print(c[i][j]+"\t"); 
 }   
 System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int[][] productTable(int r, int c){
int [][] table = new int[r][c];
for (int row = 0; row < table.length ; row++)
{
  for (int column = 0; column < table[row].length; column++)
     {
        table[row][column] = (row)*(column);
      }

    }
    return table;
}
```